# How can I use multiple RSpec contexts across a single example?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a set of contexts with given `before` clauses that I'd like to wrap around various examples. Here's my attempt:

```rb
# The "multi-context" wrapper
def with_foo_and_bar(&block)
  before { p 'hello world' }

  context 'foo' do
    before { p 'baz' }
    yield
  end

  context 'bar' do
    before { p 'qux' }
    yield
  end
end

# The example
describe do
  with_foo_and_bar do
    it 'prints some stuff' do
      # Example runs twice, but only 'hello world' is printed
    end
  end
end
```

In this spec, I would expect all `before` clauses to run and print out "baz" and "qux" once each and "hello world" twice, but only "hello world" is printed (twice, as expected). I feel like there's some problem with the `yield` ignoring the `before` blocks, but I'm not sure how to tweak the code to get what I want. I'd appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer hinted at here:

https://www.jorgemanrubia.com/2010/01/16/using-macros-to-create-custom-example-groups-in-rspec/

The solution is to do the following:

```
def with_foo_and_bar(&block)
  foo = context 'foo' do
    before { p 'baz' }
  end
  foo.class_eval &block

  bar = context 'bar' do
    before { p 'qux' }
  end
  bar.class_eval &block
end

describe do
  with_foo_and_bar do
    it 'prints some stuff' do
      # Prints 'baz' once and 'qux' once
    end
  end
end
```